# Dial between two emulators does not work

Tags: calls, android-emulator

Today, I had installed the latest Android SDK and created two emulators (Nexus 6), I then tried to dial from one emulator to another.

Based on [Make incoming call in Android emulator without command code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18460621/how-to-make-incoming-call-in-android-emulator-without-commad-code), 
I just dial `5556` from the emulator of `5554`.
But there is no receiving call in emulator-5554.

The name of the second emulator is emulator-5556 so I guess that it is correct to just dial 5556, right?

I tried to reinstall SDK, but it still the same.

Is there any idea what's wrong ?